# How To submit a form to third party when SSL is configured on the site

Tags: javascript, forms, http, https, action

I have a form that have action on third party that is using http links but my site is configured with SSL and using HTTPS links, now when i submit the from on HTTP link it give an error of block contents

MY FORM is:

```
 <form method="GET" action="http://republicmoving.moveeasy.com/move/iframe_inventory/" target="my-iframe" id="initial-move-info-form">
```

How to Figure this out. I have tried many things like adding double Forward slash to the action as ://republicmoving.moveeasy.com/move/iframe_inventory/

And Also tried javascript as:

```
var form = document.getElementById("initial-move-info-form");
form.action = location.href.replace(/^http:/, 'https:');
```

But nothing works please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

You can't because the target of your form is an iframe.

You can't show an https lock to the user to tell him it's secure and in the same time submit and display informations in an insecure way.

Comment: yeah i realized that we cant send information from Secure URLs to Insecure @Tom